# finding components of Composite Class in java Swing

Tags: java, swt

I need to find all components of Composite class(swt.widgets.composite).How to do that?
Please guide me...

Regards
Kumar

Comment: just for your information, Swing and SWT are two different libraries.

Comment: I want to find all different buttons and tabs that are there in Composite class of SWT..

Answer (score 2):

Try `public Control[] getChildren()`